# Waiting for SKAction completion inside a for loop

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I have a for loop that runs 10 times, each time creating a node and adding it to the scene. However, I want there to be a delay in between each node being added (add a node, wait a second, add a node, wait a second, etc.)

However, after the first 1 second, all 10 nodes are added at the same time. How can I achieve this desired effect of waiting a second in between each node being added?

Here is my code:

EDIT:

```
func createText(correct: Bool) {
        let text = SKNode()
        var line: String!

        addChild(text)

        if correct {
            line = (GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray(happyLines) as! [String])[0]
        } else {
            line = (GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray(sadLines) as! [String])[0]
        }

        var xPos = self.frame.midX + 300
        var yPos = self.frame.midY

        var spaces = 1

        // For each character in sentence, create a node of it
        for character in line.characters {
        runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0)) {
            if spaces == 4 {
                spaces = 0
                print("space")
                xPos = self.frame.midX + 300
                yPos -= 30
            }

            xPos += 10

            if character != " " {
                let letter = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: GameScene.fontName)
                letter.fontSize = 14 * GameScene.fontScale
                letter.position = CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos)
                letter.text = String(character)
                text.addChild(letter)
            } else {
                spaces += 1
                xPos += 10
            }

        }
    }

        runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0)) {
            text.removeAllChildren()
            text.removeFromParent()
        }

    }
```

Comment: Build an action sequence(wait,block,wait,block...) in a for loop. This way you will make a block per node (character). If you need more info, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using actions.

First, create actions for the delay and adding the node to the scene.

```
let waitAction = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)
let addNodeAction = SKAction.run {
    let node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "example")
    self.addChild(node)
}
```

Next, create a sequence of actions so that the delay always occurs before the node is added to the scene.

```
let sequenceAction = SKAction.sequence([waitAction, addNodeAction])
```

Next, create an action that repeats the sequence 10 times.

```
let repeatAction = SKAction.repeat(sequenceAction, count: 10)
```

Finally, run this action and watch the nodes appear!

```
run(repeatAction)
```

---

EDIT:

To solve your second question in the comments about needing access to the current character (making each action where the node is added slightly different), loop through your `characters` to build a sequence of actions, and then run that action.

```
var actions = [SKAction]()

let waitAction = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)

for character in line.characters {

    let addNodeAction = SKAction.run {
        let node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "example")
        // use the character variable here
        self.addChild(node)
    }

    actions.append(waitAction)
    actions.append(addNodeAction)

}

let sequenceAction = SKAction.sequence(actions)
run(sequenceAction)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I kind of simplified my problem and I don't know if this strategy will work for my actual implementation. I edited my answer to my actual code

Comment: I don't think I can use this strategy because I need to iterate over a string, I used "ten times" as an example but its a little more complicated

Comment: @Brejuro I edited my answer to solve your new question.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? (not tested :)

```
for (i, character) in line.characters.enumerate() {
   runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(Double(i) * 1.0)) {
       // rest of your for loop
```

So you enumerate through the characters, where i is the i-th character, starting at 0. With each character, you just multiply its index position in the string with the 1 second interval to give you the wait duration.